# Fluent NHibernate creates Tables with my user name as a prefix

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate

Im new to nhibernet and tried to create a test-program. So I created Entities and mapping files for Fluent NHibernate as described here: https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Getting-started

Entity:

```
namespace NHibernateDemoApp
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Map:

```
class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
    }
}
```

Then I used them like this:

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateFluidSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
      .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString("Data Source=mydatabase;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False")
      )
      .Mappings(m =>
        m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
       .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
      .BuildSessionFactory();
}

private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
{
    new SchemaExport(config)
      .Create(false, true);
}
```

Everything looks fine but NHibernet has created the table with my Username as a prefix. So the table-creation looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyDomain\MyUsername].[Employee](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

but it should be created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyDatabase].[Employee](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I start my testprogram as another user, the table gets created twice (one for each user).

What Im doing wrong? How to tell hibernet that there should be no username in the tablecreation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter the default schema. It's an NH configuration setting. Ensure you have database permission to create tables within the dbo schema.

You should be able to do something like:

```
return 
    Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(
            MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
                .ConnectionString("Data Source=mydatabase;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFai9lover=False")
                .DefaultSchema("dbo"))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
        .BuildSessionFactory();
```

The option hangs off the configuration type: https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Database-configuration

Comment: I have the database permissions. But how to alter the "default schema"?

Comment: @Gener4tor I've added an example to the answer.